# Store pointer pointing to object contained in map

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, reference, dictionary

Im wondering whether this snippet of code will actually store a pointer pointing to object which is managed by a map:

```
std::map<std::string,MapType> map;
MapType* typePointer;

typePointer = map[someKey];
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typePointer = &map[someKey];
```

Comment: @juanchopanza How? `map::operator[]` returns a reference, which can't be null, and the map in question does not store pointers so it can't be a reference-to-null (which wouldn't be nearly as bad - you could simply overwrite it).

Comment: @delnan yes, sorry. I got confused with OP's storing pointer to (object in map) vs storing (pointer to object) in map.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won’t.

You are storing the `MapType`, not `MapType*` inside the map. Consequently, the last line is a type mismatch and won’t compile.

Comment: But the operator[] actually returns a reference to a MapType object. Thats why im confused in this case. Can i assign a reference directly to a pointer?

Comment: @juanchopanza Beside that this is not very helpful to me, i thought that the term "pointer to object in map" could be clearly interpreted as "pointer pointing to object which is stored in a map". I have to admit that it might be missleading. I will change the question.

Comment: @Paranaix I think the confusion is because your question title can be parsed in two ways, and is ambiguous. You want a pointer to an (object in a map), some of us thought you wanted a (pointer to an object) stored in a map.

Comment: @Paranaix References and pointers are totally different things.